# AngularJS: Apply a class depends on variable

Tags: angularjs

I've got an array of object where each has a color variable ('success', 'danger', 'info'). I have to apply them on panels, texts and buttons, just like that:

```
<div class="panel" ng-class="panel-{{panel.color}}"></div>
<button class="btn" ng-class="btn-{{panel.color}}"></div>
<p ng-class="text-{{panel.color}}"></p>
```

Of course, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try with class instead of ng-class ?

Comment: You're not using `ng-class` correctly, should read about _ngClass_ API here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass. Otherwise use `ng-attr-class`.

Comment: @Fieldset, your solution works. Make an answer, not a comment and I will approve it.

Comment: `ng-class` is useful if you want to add and remove classes dynamically, but if you just want to interpolate a variable use `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Why it does not work ?

The reason why this code `ng-class="panel-{{panel.color}}"` doesn't work is that you are confusing `ng-class` directive which accepts variables names without doubles curly braces and `class` attribute which requires doubles curly braces around the variables names.

### 2. How to fix it ?

There are two ways to do it :

One way with `ng-class` :

```
<span ng-class="'panel-'+panel.color">panel {{panel.color}}</span>
```

Another one with `class` :

```
<span class="panel-{{panel.color}}">panel {{panel.color}}</span>
```

## [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fieldset/9s1hsLhk/)

### 3. ngClass directive is very handy

There are many ways to use ngClass.

You can pass an array of class names :

```
<span ng-class="['panel-'+panel.color, 'panel-'+panel.primary]">panel </span>
```

Or you can conditionally add classes :

```
<span ng-class="{'panel-red' : panel.isRed, 'panel-primary': panel.isPrimary}">panel</span>
```

Or use ternary operator :

```
<span ng-class="panel.isRed ? 'panel-red' : 'panel-not-red'">panel</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngClass like this:

```
<!-- input box to toggle a variable to true or false -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="awesome"> Are You Awesome?
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="giant"> Are You a Giant?

<!-- add the class 'text-success' if the variable 'awesome' is true -->
<div ng-class="{ 'text-success': awesome, 'text-large': giant }">
```

or

```
ng-class="x > 4 ? 'success' : 'danger'">
```

Instead of x >4 put your condition

Here you can find lot's of real examples:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass